# How to convert "-?" from Perl Regex to c# regex

Tags: c#, regex, perl, translation, code-conversion

I couldn't find any documentation on this symbol.  What does "-?" mean when it precedes a parenthetical expression?

**Update** - The example I saw is the integer and float regex constraints on the WebIDL specification.  Here is a direct link to the grammar appendix:  http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/WebIDL/#idl-grammar

Comment: I'm wondering if he means e.g. `(?-i:pattern)`

Comment: @BoltClock, I have posted the context/link.

Comment: It's an optional `-`, it is written the same way (meaning the same thing) both regex flavors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty standard for «`-?`» to mean "match the character «`-`» zero or one times".

```
$ perl -E'
   say "$_: ", /^aaa-?bbb\z/ ? "match" : "no match"
      for qw( aaabbb aaa-bbb aaa--bbb );
'
aaabbb: match
aaa-bbb: match
aaa--bbb: no match
```

I'd be extremely surprised if it didn't work the same way in C#.

Comment: There is similar behavior with a `?` in C#.  However, the `?` has to be a quantifier appearing at the end of a pattern.  The Perl context that I saw had the entire pattern prefixed with `-?`.

Comment: I could see that making sense for the regex, I was looking at (even as a prefix).  Do you have any supporting documentation?

Comment: Well, the regexes you linked are supposed to match numbers; numbers may or may not be negative; a negative number starts with a `-`. So it makes sense to start the pattern with `-?` to handle that. It's not a "prefix", it's normal regex.